# List all files in a sub-folder in a given branch / tag

Tags: github

I have been spending the last couple of hours trying to figure out a way to reliably list all the files in a given git repo's sub-folder. For example, if I want to list all files under in the repo -

```
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java
```

under the tag -

```
/tree/1.11.244
```

using the github api v3 or v4, could anyone please point me in the direction on the different steps to be done for this? Also, if we have a lot of files, is there a way I could add a file filter to look for a file pattern to list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `ref` parameter when [listing contents](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path?ref=:ref
```

And if you want it to be recursive you can use `recursive=1`

For example

```
GET /repos/user/my_repo/contents/tests/units?ref=0.1
```

If I want to see the files in `tests/units` under tag `0.1`, with `curl` it would look like:

```
curl -u user:pass -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/user/my_repo/contents/tests/units?ref=0.1
```

Unfortunately I don't think you can add a query string to a request to this endpoint (also this endpoint has a maximum 1000 files to retrieve from a directory, if you have more you are going to need the [Git Trees API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree))

Comment: while I was able to accomplish what I need to do based on your response, is there a way to get this list of files using v4 graph API ? I tried exploring and could only reach as much as listing the tags in a repo and beyond that I couldn't figure out how to list files. Any inputs ? If this has to be a separate question, I can understand. Thanks.